# How to mass edit the format of cells in a CSV file - Excel 2013

Tags: excel, csv, url, cells

Right now I have a CSV file with thousands of URLs. Each row contains a URL in this format: `5,google.com` and this `1750,facebook.com`. Each number is a URL count.

Basically I want to change the format to this: `http://www.google.com` for all URLs so I can import the CSV to a python script and do some crawling on the URLs.

I managed to automatically add `http://www.` in front of all thousands URLs by custom formatting the cells. But I couldn't get rid of the counting numbers and the `,` in front of the URLs. Now I'm stuck with this: `http://www.1,google.com`.

How do I automatically sort these URLs to the desired format as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula.  If your text is in column A then enter this formula in B1 and autofill down.

```
="http://www." & RIGHT(I16,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1,1))
```

Also, you can make each cell a hyperlink

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www." & RIGHT(I16,LEN(I16)-FIND(",",A1,1)),"http://www." & RIGHT(I16,LEN(I16)-FIND(",",A1,1)))
```